# How do I check if the user is in fullscreen mode in IE6 using scripting?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, fullscreen

I'm using scripting to turn the IE6 screen to full screen mode. I'm using the Wscript.Shell ActiveX object and sending the F11 key to IE. The problem is that if the user enters again to the screen it sends the F11 key again and it returns to normal screen. I tried to save the information in the user's session but when it ends the problem returns.

Did someone find a way of telling if the user is currently in full screen in IE6 using scripting?

Thanks.

Comment: Which scripting language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to some [example Javascript code](http://javascript.internet.com/navigation/full-screen.html) that opens a new browser window fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked over the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873(VS.85).aspx#) of the `window` object and it doesn't indicate any property which provides the information you're looking for.  My guess is that it's not possible.